# Why does unittest require __init__.py to be present in Python 3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.6, python-unittest

I just come across this line in python3.6 unittest (`/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py:286`):

```
is_not_importable = not os.path.isfile(os.path.join(start_dir, '__init__.py'))
```

which caused the unittest discovery to fail to run my tests. Why is this line still present in python3.6 library (Ubuntu 17.10, I don't know if it matters), if `__init__.py` is no longer required since python3.3?

I believe that's a bug, but I want a confirmation.

When there's no `__init__.py` in the `foo` directory, the following command runs fine (`{PROJECT_HOME}` being a placeholder):

```
python3.6 -m unittest discover tests.foo -t {PROJECT_HOME} -p "*.py"
```

while this fails (with `ImportError: Start directory is not importable`):

```
python3.6 -m unittest discover tests/foo -t {PROJECT_HOME} -p "*.py"
```

The difference being . -> / When there is `__init__.py`, both commands work the same.

Comment: I believe it's pretty clear that it's a placeholder. I'll edit the question if that's not the case.

Comment: Hm, I think I realized that you're trying to say me that -s option is not appended to -t value. But in my case it doesn't  matter, since my {PROJECT_HOME} was just a `.`.

Comment: Looking into this a little deeper, it looks like when you specify a top level directory and a start directory as a file system path, the loader thinks you are explicitly asking to load tests configured in the start directory's `__init__.py`. I'm guessing that they raise an `ImportError` in this case because there's no reasonable way to determine that the start directory should be treated as a namespace package (because of file system semantics versus package semantics). It definitely seems like the docs could be a little more clear about this.

Comment: I don't get yet why assuming that it's a package would be bad. Care to elaborate?

Comment: I'm not saying it's a bad package. It just seems to be (not entirely sure) that when you use a file system path for the start directory _and_ the top level directory is different from the start directory, the loader doesn't know (or try to guess) that you want the start directory to be treated as a namespace package.

Comment: I mean: if the loader assumed I always want it to be treated as a namespace package - could it bring any negative consequences? Because I can't think of any

Comment: For that to work in general, the start directory would have to be imported, but to do that, the loader would have to figure out how to turn the file system path into a package path. In your case here, that _seems_ like it would be pretty straightforward because it could just convert `tests/foo` to `tests.foo`, but in general it would have to know how to turn arbitrary file system paths into package paths, and I don't think there's a great way to do that.

Comment: Alright, so it seems that is not as much a bug, as a feature request (to convert relative paths). I mean I could just use dots, but I don't think it's easibly configurable in Pycharm. Or maybe I should ask jetbrains to use dots by default when right-clicking. Thank you

Comment: Hi, to whoever gave -1 point to my answer, I would really appreciate if you could elaborate why the answer was not useful, to allow me improve it, thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Python repository directories depend on **init**.py to control python's behaviour when importing modules.

So you have to follow the guidelines in [packaging namespace packages](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/)

Most cases will use the [native namespace packages](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/#native-namespace-packages)

Another important thing is the [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) because it is an environment variable which you can set to add additional directories where python will look for modules and packages. For most installations, you should not set these variables since they are not needed for Python to run. Python knows where to find its standard library.

The only reason to set is to maintain directories of custom Python libraries that you do not want to install in the global default location (i.e., the site-packages directory).